# How to access API metadata (e.g. category counts that come from elasticsearch) in react-admin ListContext

Tags: react-admin, faceted-search

I have a graphql API that uses elasticsearch to retrieve list results. The API responses has a 'meta' key that contains the aggregations for the facets present in the search results.

I want to provide a custom filter for users in the react-admin list view that only shows options for each facet's filter that are actually present in the response (e.g. if the list has items with colours `red` and `green`, only show `red` and `green` as options for the `Colours` filter.

I can't figure out how to make this work. So far I have this code:

```
const FilterForm = () => {
    const { displayedFilters, filterValues, setFilters, hideFilter, data, isLoading } =
        useListContext();

    const filters = ????

    const form = useForm({
        defaultValues: filterValues
    });

    console.log("filters: ", filters);

    if (!displayedFilters.main) {
        return null;
    }

    const onSubmit = (values: { [key: string]: string }) => {
        if (Object.keys(values).length > 0) {
            setFilters(values, displayedFilters);
        } else {
            hideFilter("main");
        }
    };

        return (
            <FormProvider {...form}>
                <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <Box display="flex" alignItems="flex-end" mb={1}>
                        {Object.keys(filters).map((filterKey: string) => {
                            return (
                                <SelectInput
                                    key={filterKey}
                                    source={filterKey}
                                    choices={Object.keys(filters[filterKey]).map(value => ({
                                        id: value,
                                        name: value
                                    }))}
                                />
                            );
                        })}{" "}
                    </Box>
                </form>
            </FormProvider>
        );
};
```

I tried to access the meta object from the ListContext, but there doesn't seem to be a way to pass it into the context from the dataprovider.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you are following https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FilteringTutorial.html#using-the-custom-filters-in-the-list-actions, then the `FilterForm` should be able to access the `ListContext` and retrieve its `data`, which should contain the `meta` field if your dataProvider returns it correctly. So this is weird. Alternatively, you can use [useGetList](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useGetList.html) again in your `FilterForm` to specifically fetch for the metadata and use them to populate the choices.